# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' in windows powershell

Tags: python, mysql, windows, powershell-2.0, mysql-connector

I have successfully installed mysql-connector.I am running a python program "videos.py" in windows powershell.
But still I am getting the error saying :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File ".\videos.py", line 1, in <module>
  from db import conn, update, select, insert
  File "C:\wamp64\www\cvm\python\db.py", line 1, in <module>
  import mysql.connector
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I have tried with
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf

pip install mysql-connector

pip list

- and I see mysql-connector in the list
  But yet there is the same error.

Comment: Did you use PS to run `pip`? Or an IDE or CMD? Please show *how* you are running script in PS. You may have multiple Python versions installed with `mysql` installed on one. Check if 32/64 bitness matches between both Python and PowerShell. Can you launch `python` shell inside PowerShell and try `import` line?

Comment: Yes I am using PS to run pip and I have multiple versions of python